# How to unify date formats

Tags: php, python-3.x, datetime, strtotime, strptime

I am trying to unify different date formats from a google sheet. I downloaded the file as a csv and started trying but the problem is that I have quite different formats. I initially started with python but did not reformat everything. I tried to use strtotime() from php but it did not give correct results because sometimes the format is mm-dd-yyyy and sometimes it is yyyy. All I really care about is the last 2 digits of the year. If it is "8/3/2012" then all I need is the "12". This is the python code that gave me the best result, but still did not clean everything.

```
import csv

f = open('ViceNews_FullOISData.csv', encoding='latin-1', newline='')
reader = csv.reader(f)

o = open('clean.csv', 'w', encoding='latin-1', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(o)

count = 0
for row in reader:
    if len(row[0].strip()) == 4:
        writer.writerow(row)
        count = count + 1
    else:
        date_d = row[0]
        if date_d[-4:].find("-") != -1 or date_d[-4:].find("/") != -1:
            year_c = date_d[:4] 
        else:
            year_c = date_d[-4:]
        row[0] = year_c
        writer.writerow(row)
        count = count + 1
print (count)
f.close()
o.close()
```

Any advice is appreciated. Here is the file on Google docs:
[csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CaOQ7FUYsGFCHEqGzA2hlfj69sx3GE9GoJ40OcqI9KY/edit#gid=1271324584)

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, it is simple, you just have to use the function `date()` like this :

```
// let's say the date field value from your csv is in a var called 
$csv_date_value

$year = date('y', strtotime($csv_date_value));
```

EDIT ------

So i tried something that worked well, here is the code i used :

```
$date = new Datetime();
$date = date_create_from_format('Y', '2010');
echo date('Y', $date->getTimestamp()); // returns 2010
echo date('y', $date->getTimestamp()); // returns 10
```

you can check for the date function on [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: echo date('y', strtotime("2010")); is printing 18. I've already tried that.

Comment: and if you try with `date('Y', strtotime($csv_date_value));` ? it should returns you the year over 4 digits, then you'll just have to take off the 2 firsts one

Comment: I tried that, I was giving you an example where strtotime fails.